# AJAX-CodeIgniter URL parameter file path

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My directory is build-up like this

```
Project Folder
--applications
    --common files
--assets
    --base
        --css
        --js
    --images
    --plugins
--system
--user_guide
```

and I got a function like this in a `file assets/base/js` js file.

```
function reqAjaxData(link, data){
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url:link,
        type:"POST",
        data:{data:data},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(a){
            return a;
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

And the JavaScript for the main page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#in_log", function (){
        link = "<?php echo base_url('assets/base/js/someJsFile.js');?>";
        reqAjaxData(link, data);
    });
});
```

My problem is that how to access the php file in the `base_url()+"/assets/base/js/somephpfile.php/"` when I use AJAX. I got things connected but I am stuck at what to use for the `link` variable in the third set of codes I presented here.

Edit: I got a headache and I missed my real question. My problem here is what `link` should I use when I put my php file is in the `helper` folder inside the `application` folder. Also if you see some problems in my codes, I really love to have some answers to those problems.

Comment: Why do you have your `someJsFile.js` in the `link` variable now, that does not make any sense whatsoever? And what is your actual question/problem here? If you have a function that provides the base URL, then what else are you still missing to be able to create the appropriate absolute URL to your PHP script that you want to make the AJAX request to?

Comment: Note that `return` in `success` does nothing...there is nowhere to return to. Also never ever use `async:false` ... it is a terrible practice and is deprecated. Beyond that it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Edited the question: Got some "laggy" bugs in my head now. Anyway. @charlietfl - Why it is bad to make async false? And thanks for the `return` one. It reminds me that this is not `php`

Comment: Because it completely blocks the UI during request which can cause serious issues if it is a long request or times out